# Calculating orders and quantity for sql query

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon Stack Overflow community! I'm pretty new to sql and writing queries, so if someone could just double check my work and maybe pass along any helpful tips at how I might go about coding it better? I've pasted along the purpose of the query and my code - I appreciate the help and feedback thanks!

*Basically the query should create a report of customers living in Europe who have recently placed an order totaling more than $5,000. Order total must reflect the quantity of the products the customer ordered, which should also have a discount and order total.*

Thanks again for the help!

```
select c.CustomerID, c.Country, sum (od.Discount * od.UnitPrice)'Total'
from Customers c
inner join Orders o
on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
inner join OrderDetails od
on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
where c.Country in ('germany', 'UK', 'sweden', 'france', 'spain', 'switzerland','austria', 'italy', 'belgium', 'norway', 'denmark', 'finland', 'poland') 
group by c.Country, c.CustomerID
having sum ('Total' * od.Quantity) <= 5000
order by total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks good, but for a couple of points: 
1) Your `Total` may be wrong
2) You must reverse the comparison operator:

```
select c.CustomerID, c.Country, sum (od.Discount * od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) 'Total'
from Customers c
inner join Orders o
on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
inner join OrderDetails od
on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
where c.Country in ('germany', 'UK', 'sweden', 'france', 'spain', 
  'switzerland','austria', 'italy', 'belgium', 'norway', 'denmark', 
  'finland', 'poland') 
and o.OrderDate >= '2017-03-01' -- for example
group by c.Country, c.CustomerID
having sum ( od.Discount * od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) >= 5000
order by total desc
```

Comment: I edited the answer, as there is no code corresponding to the "recently" part of your question, perhaps you need to add an extra criterion to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, appreciate your help and feedback!